# Replacements for Sound Analysis Pro 2011 given Compatibility Issues

Tags: recording, birdsong, software

We are working a lot with audio recordings from songbirds in our lab. For the past decade, everybody was using a custom software called [Sound Analysis Pro 2011 (SAP2011)](http://www.soundanalysispro.com) for a plethora of tasks. The beauty of the software is that it allows you to simultaneously run experiments (e.g. playbacks), trigger recordings and process the recorded audio files.

Now, SAP2011 has been discontinued since and we slowly start to run into compatibility issues as it's 11 years old and my question thus is if anybody faces similar problems or already found ways to avoid compatibility problems without implementing hardware updates.

Or is there is an alternative software out there that we are simply not aware of that allows for a comparable functionality? I am aware of various softwares that provide comparable capabilities (e.g. Raven, Avisoft etc.) but  not under the same hood.

Looking forward for all kinds of suggestions and workarounds!

Answer (score 5):

I have no experience with Sound Analysis Pro (so I cannot comment on backwards compatibility and am uncertain of the full suite of capabilities that you would be missing out on if you were to move to another software), ... but I can mention an alternative: **[PAMGuard](https://www.pamguard.org/)**. This free, open-source software for passive acoustic monitoring has the functionalities you specified (playbacks, making recordings, analysing acoustic files).

While originally made for the marine environment, there is a terrestrial mode that you can toggle to to accomodate those you study bats/birds (*e.g*. taking into account the different reference units of dB re 1 uPa for in-water measurements or dB re 20 uPa for in-air measurements).

Comment: PAMGuard works on Windows OS only :'-()

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend Tessa Rhinehart's amazing list of bioacoustics software. The list is grouped by functionality too, so you can see what options would be best for your specific use cases.

https://github.com/rhine3/bioacoustics-software